# Kotlin and spring boot data resource exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data

I'm trying out kotlin and spring boot with spring data.

```
id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.1.8.RELEASE"
```

I have some `schema-*.sql` files in `src/main/resources`. I put this in my `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.schema=/sql/schema-*.sql
```

I then made a small spring boot `ApplicationRunner`-based app (so set `WebApplicationType.NONE`) and these all get executed as expected and the app starts fine.

```
@SpringBootApplication
private class MainApp(): ApplicationRunner { ... }

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  runApplication<MainApp>(*args) {
    webApplicationType = WebApplicationType.NONE
  }
}
```

Now, when I change the above to `WebApplicationType.SERVLET`, I get the following:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/sql/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getURL(ServletContextResource.java:173) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findPathMatchingResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:498) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:298) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ClassLoaderFilesResourcePatternResolver.getResources(ClassLoaderFilesResourcePatternResolver.java:109) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext.getResources(GenericApplicationContext.java:233) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.config.SortedResourcesFactoryBean.createInstance(SortedResourcesFactoryBean.java:76) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.config.SortedResourcesFactoryBean.createInstance(SortedResourcesFactoryBean.java:42) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:142) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.doGetResources(DataSourceInitializer.java:175) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 89 common frames omitted
```

This exception goes away and the http server seems to be fine when I omment out:

```
spring.datasource.schema=/sql/schema-*.sql
```

Any ideas what I'm supposed to change to make this work?

Comment: Try `spring.datasource.schema=classpath:sql/schema-*.sql`

Comment: @AlexeyUsharovski Cool, that worked, can you post as an answer please?

Comment: @AlexeyUsharovski Btw, any idea why changing `WebApplicationType` changes how this works?

Comment: Interesting about `WebApplicationType` but I have no suggestions for now worth to spread... Going to think about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that `spring.datasource.schema=classpath:sql/schema-*.sql`.